# PHP how to convert number exponential number to string?

Tags: php, string, floating-point, number-formatting, exponential

I have a number stored in scientific notation

> 2.01421700079E+14

I've tried using float, string, int and I can't get

> 0201421700079085 **from** 2.01421700079E+14

```
1. echo (float)$awb;
2. echo number_format($awb, 0, '', '');
3. echo (int)$awb;
4. echo (string)$awb;
```

1. 2.01421700079E+14 = float
2. 201421700079085 = number
3. 201421700079085 = int
4. 2.01421700079E+14 = string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`printf`](http://php.net/printf) and friends will do this:

```
<?php
$awb = 2.01421700079E+14;
$str = sprintf("%d", $awb);
var_dump($str);
```

Output:

```
string(15) "201421700079000"
```

There obviously isn't enough information in your original number to get any more precision than that.

Comment: may be different if result 0201421700079085, do you have new solution for me ?

Comment: You can't just invent numbers. You have a certain amount of precision in your input, you don't get any more precision than that.

Comment: is for a import from excel to mysql but if i want to upload in mysql show this number 2.01421700079E+14, but in my excel is number 0201421700079085, do you have any solution for me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
number_format(1.2378147769392E+14,0,'','')
```

Comment: i try your code and result is 201421700079085 but i want result is 0201421700079085 with zero in front because the number string is 0201421700079085

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php

try these libraries for better precision. default php libraries only provide limited functionalities in such case