# how can i convert 5.0E+22 to string in php

Tags: php, scientific-notation

I am trying to a do a big calculation for example:

```
$a = 50000 * 1000000000000000000;
```

the result its 5.0E+22 in php

how can I convert it or print it as "50000000000000000000000" as string, cause it's not possible in int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP how to convert number exponential number to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510301/php-how-to-convert-number-exponential-number-to-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This number is actually too large for an integer representation in PHP and converting to a float won't get the precision for this number.   When doing math that requires huge numbers or accurate precision, it's best to use bc math with strings.

```
echo bcmul("50000", "1000000000000000000");
// prints "50000000000000000000000"
```